# Django Conflict between 2 pagination

Tags: django

I'm trying to display all the data assoicated to every person and every house on an single template each with pagination.
The problem is everytime I view the entries of a particular data using pagination example person. The other pagination called house get reseted.
For example if I am on page 3 for house and I try to view other entries for page person . The house pagination will get reset back to 1. How do I fix this pagination conflict?

models

```
class Person(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class House(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views

```
def Display(request):
        user= User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        comment = Person.objects.get(user=user)

        posts = House.objects.filter(user=user)

        paginator = Paginator(comment, 5)

        try: n = int(request.GET.get("n", '1'))
        except ValueError: page = 1

        try:
            comment = paginator.page(n)
        except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
            comment = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)





        paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)

        try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
        except ValueError: page = 1

        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render(request,'display.html',{'posts':posts,'comment':comment})
```

HTML

```
{% for p in posts.object_list %}
{{p.name}}
{% endfor %}


    {% if posts.object_list and posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    <div class="pagination" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: -20px; ">


                &nbsp;Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}<br>

            {% if posts.has_previous %}
                <a class="Link" href= "{% if formula %}?text={{formula}}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if posts.has_next %}
                <a class="Link" href="{% if formula %}?text={{formula}}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ posts.next_page_number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>

            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}


{% for c in comment.object_list %}
{{c.name}}
{% endfor %}

    {% if comment.object_list and comment.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}


                &nbsp;Page {{ comment.number }} of {{ comment.paginator.num_pages }}
                {% if comment.has_previous %}
                <a class="Link" href= "?n={{ comment.previous_page_number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
            {% endif %}<br>
            {% if comment.has_next %}
                <a class="Link" href="?n={{ comment.next_page_number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>

            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %
```

Comment: One thing I see wrong, the first line of your `Display` view, move your `comment = Person.objects.get(user=user)` down one line since `user` doesn't exist yet (you have it set on the line below it).

Comment: okay thank you . Now the big issue "conflict with pagination"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your variable names versus how you describe everything is quite confusing.

The issue is you are using two different variables for the page: `n` for `person` (or `comment`) and `page` for `house` (or posts). In each of your `<a href="">` you need to set both `n` and `page` not just one. So:

```
<a class="Link" href= "{% if formula %}?text={{formula}}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}&n={{ comment.number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
<a class="Link" href="{% if formula %}?text={{formula}}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ posts.next_page_number }}&n={{ comment.number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>

<a class="Link" href= "?n={{ comment.previous_page_number }}&page={{ posts.number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
<a class="Link" href="?n={{ comment.next_page_number }}&page={{ posts.number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>
```

Comment: sorry how I describe the variable

Answer (score 0):

In the same view you change the value of `paginator` two times

```
paginator = Paginator(comment, 5)

# here you have code that does stuff and some lines below

paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)
```

if you want two paginators in the same view you should also name them differently (and add them to your context variables)

Something I can suggest is to have an ajax pagination view that you're going to call to switch between pages in your templates. In this way, you can change page to each resultset separately without needing to reload the entire view (and probably loosing your pagination state)

Comment: @Jacob - while I agree that this answer provided also points out a potential issue (not error, sorry for my original comment), it will not solve your original problem. See my answer.

Comment: @Jacob yeah, themanatuf is correct: if you simply want your current problem solved, just go by his solution. Mine was mostly a suggestion on how you can actually improve your code using a better designed solution :)